# How to increase font size in dlookr eda_web_report?

Tags: r, font-size, dlookr

I am playing around with `dlookr` package:

When I use:

```
library(dlookr)

eda_web_report(mtcars[, 1:2])
```

I get:
[image]

How can we tweak the font size of the correlation plot?